# ETH Based GPU Pools After Casper

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu

I've been reading a bit about Casper lately and I've seen that a lot of the miners are upset because they think their GPUs will become useless but there are tons of uses for GPUs besides cryptocurrency mining.

Has anyone thought about setting up smart contracts where people could contribute GPU power to pools that researchers could buy from, then the 'miners' could be rewarded with ETH?  That would help miners accept Casper more easily, helping to prevent another ETC/ETH type split and the GPU power would go to seriously useful things like machine learning, analyzing medical imagery, computational fluid dynamics, weather forecasting, etc.

Comment: Hi, nice question but a little bit too open for stack exchange IMO.